# Can we use accordion and tabs simultaneously on single page in wordpress in wp bakery's visual composer?

Tags: wordpress

I have added visual composer plugin into my wordpress theme and I want to use tabs and accordion simultaneously on wp bakery's visual composer.

Accordions are working properly, but tabs are not working: only the content of the active tab is shown, and other tabs are not clickable.

Comment: Is there any code involved, so that others can reproduce the problem?